# What is the NSURLSession in general?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

What is `NSURLSession`? Is it a connection to a website or a server?

I am confused by this kind of concept.

Comment: If you are confused about a **concept** then you should always [refer to the **Conceptual** documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)

Comment: I read it several times...I know it is an API, but could itself connect a website or a server?

Comment: Yes, it's designed to submit requests to website/server via HTTP. But `NSURLSession` is not a "connection" to a server, but rather serves a broader role: A session can initiate a series of "tasks" (i.e. requests). I'd suggest you watch WWDC 2013 video [What's New in Foundation Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-705/) which introduces you to `NSURLSession`.

Comment: Thank you for your patient reply. I decided to understand it in practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer apple documentation for that. Refer [Apple reference guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/)

> The NSURLSession class and related classes provide an API for downloading content. This API provides a rich set of delegate methods for supporting authentication and gives your app the ability to perform background downloads when your app is not running or, in iOS, while your app is suspended.
>
> With the NSURLSession API, your app creates one or more sessions, each of which coordinates a group of related data transfer tasks. For example, if you are writing a web browser, your app might create one session per tab or window, or one session for interactive use and another session for background downloads. Within each session, your app adds a series of tasks, each of which represents a request for a specific URL (following HTTP redirects if necessary).